# Can't get deviceId on iOS

Tags: codenameone

I develop an app that uses push notifications. On Android I receive deviceId from pushRegistered(String deviceId) method, and push notification works great. On iOS it doesn't work.
I got iOS certificates with includePush=true, in build hints there is includePush=true. When I run the app, pushRegistered(String deviceId), pushRegistrationError(String error, int errorCode) methods does nothing. Down below is code for tests. What should I do/check to receive deviceId?

```
@Override
public void registeredForPush(String deviceId) {
    this.deviceId = "registered id: " + deviceId; //TODO delete
    new DLG02GeneralInfo("PUSH REGISTRATION", "deviceId: " + deviceId, "OK", null).show();
}

@Override
public void pushRegistrationError(String error, int errorCode) {
    new DLG02GeneralInfo("PUSH REGISTRATION ERROR", "error: " + error + " errorCode: " + errorCode , "OK", null).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `registeredForPush` is invoked all should be good. But you shouldn't use `deviceId`. Use `Push.getPushKey()` which should return a valid result once `registeredForPush` is invoked.

Comment: Hi Shai, main problem is that registeredForPush is not invoked. Is there a build hint for push notifications that I am missing? (note: i got includePush=true) Or is there something wrong with my iOS certificates? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you include the `ios.includePush` hint correctly through the GUI or did you edit the file? If the latter did you include the prefix required when editing the file directly?

Comment: Yes, I used GUI. Therefore when I open codenameone_settings.properties file, this line of text is there: codename1.arg.ios.includePush=true. I've also checked the validity of the Apple certificates. All certificates are valid and Active, but the PushNotiffication doesn't work. Apple profile is correct, I am able to build the Apple application from my computer without any problems. Android still works fine. I've added log message into registerForPush method, but this method in iOS is never invoked.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered what the problem was. For iOS application to register device for push notification this line of code needs to be added in `start()` method of main class:

`Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> Display.getInstance().registerPush());`

Android notifications works without that line of code.